# Is there a way where I can send HTML file in email through an approval process?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script, gmail

My goal for this is to send a conditional email containing an html body. The html body contains a css and in one part of the html, I want to pull the ticketNumber from code.gs to html. There's no failed execution based on the execution section but I haven't receive any email so I may have done something wrong in the code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"><meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"><meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"><style type="text/css">@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Staatliches&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alfa+Slab+One&family=Ubuntu&display=swap");

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

body,
html {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    display: grid;
    font-family: "Staatliches", cursive;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 100vh;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

.ticket {
    background: white;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 19px 38px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22) 0px 15px 12px;
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
}

.left {
    display: flex;
}

.image {
    background-image: url("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1eCyBxQSZy4XcdhsurTGYHmnhgq1vHfoe");
    background-size: contain;
    bottom: 
    height: 270px;
    opacity: 0.85;
    width: 250px;
}

.admit-one {
    position: absolute;
    color: darkgray;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    letter-spacing: 0.15em;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.admit-one span:nth-child(2) {
    color: #737373;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.left .ticket-number {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
    padding: 5px;
}

.ticket-info {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.date {
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
    display: flex;
    font-weight: 700;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.date span {
    width: 100px;
}

.date span:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}

.date span:last-child {
    text-align: right;
}

.date .oct-21 {
    color: #1F386E;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.show-name {
    color: #1F386E;
    font-family: "Ubuntu";
    font-size: 30px;
}

.show-name h1 {
    color: #1F386E;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.time {
    color: #1F386E;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.time span {
    color: gray;
    font-weight: 400;

}

.left .time {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.location {
    align-items: center;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    width: 100%;
}

.location .separator {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.right {
    border-left: 5px dashed #404040;
    width: 180px;

}

.right .admit-one {
    color: darkgray;
}

.right .admit-one span:nth-child(2) {
    color: gray;
}

.right .right-info-container {

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 250px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 25px 10px 10px 35px;
}

.right .show-name h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
    left: 0px;
    line-height: 0px;

}

.rofi {
    background-image: url("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1YgqYUxv6NjciPZOLiP7sxVjTGLcJ9RDm");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    bottom: 40px;
    height: 99px;
    opacity: 0.85;
    position: relative;
    top: 0.5px;
    width: 130px;
}

.right .ticket-number {
    align-items: center;
    bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    left: 30px;
    position: relative;

}</style><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">

</head><body><div class="ticket">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="image">
            <p class="admit-one">
                <span>ADMIT ONE</span>
                <span>ADMIT ONE</span>
                <span>ADMIT ONE</span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="ticket-info">
            <p class="date">
                <span>Friday</span>
                <span class="oct-21">October 21st</span>
                <span>2022</span>
            </p>
            <div class="show-name">
                <h1>001></h1>
                <h2>Ticket Number</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="time">
                <p>7:00 AM <span>TO</span> 4:00 PM</p>
                <p>Registration <span>@</span> 7:00 AM</p>
                <p>Shotgun Tee-off <span>@</span> 8:00 AM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="location"><span>Mt. Malarayat Golf &amp; Country Club Lipa Batangas</span>
        </p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p class="admit-one">
            <span>ADMIT ONE</span>
            <span>ADMIT ONE</span>
            <span>ADMIT ONE</span>
        </p>
        <div class="right-info-container">
            <div class="show-name">
                <h1>For inquiries</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="time">
                <p>Contact us at</p>
                <p>09178804200 rofi@rayomar.com.ph</p>
            </div>
            <div class="rofi"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ticket-number">
            <p> Save this ticket and present at the booth</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><script>// Write JavaScript here </script></body>
```

```js
function sendMailEdit(){
     var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
     var lastRow     = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
     var ticketNumber = spreadsheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).getValue();
     var email = spreadsheet.getRange(lastRow, 3).getValue();
     var ticketTrigger = spreadsheet.getRange(lastRow, 4).getValue();

     if (ticketTrigger == "Yes") {
        var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index').getContent();

        MailApp.sendEmail(email, "Test", htmlBody, {htmlBody: htmlBody});
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try it with `GmailApp.sendEmail()`

Comment: @Ricardas sadly I can't still receive any email

Comment: Column indexes in `getRange()` start at 1, not 0. The emails are not being sent because `ticketTrigger` contains the email address instead of "Yes". I'm not so sure how to display all the CSS in the email, though. I believe that you cannot include links to external stylesheets.